# What does 'save any winter wardrobe' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In [this paragraph](https://gabriellearruda.com/what-to-wear-with-black-tights/#:%7E:text=course%2C%20they%20save-,any%20winter%20wardrobe,-.%20However%2C%20because%20of) talking about black tights, it says:

> Black tights are best worn in the transitional months like fall and early spring, and of course, they **save any winter wardrobe**.

What does 'save any winter wardrobe' mean? I think it may be about whether to wear tights in winter.

However, [this blog](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/style-beauty/fashion/advice/a53010/winter-fashion-hacks/) makes me confused because 'save your winter wardrobe' in it means to maintain your winter clothing and make them comfortable. How can your tights maintain your winter clothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black tights 'save' a winter wardrobe in the sense that they rescue an outfit worn in winter from looking dull or uninteresting, as it might otherwise. For a man, a bright necktie might 'save' a dull looking suit.

> save verb
> (MAKE SAFE) [ T ]
> to make or keep someone or something safe from danger or harm, **or to bring something
> back to a satisfactory condition:**

[Save (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/save)